# How to ensure a place is part of the Google Places autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api

We got a customer looking after an event called Floriade placed in the city of venlo in the Netherlands. This point of interest is sometimes shown on the autocompletion under Floriade 2012. I say sometimes shown as we used to see it, then it disappeared, now it is back again.

1-How can I be sure that the autocompletion (through Google Places API) is showing this point of interest ?
2- What is enabling a point to be in this autocompletion or not ?

Answer (score 0):

If a place has a Google Places page, e.g http://maps.google.com.au/maps/place?cid=14788366310032789085 it is guaranteed to be returned by a Places Autocomplete API.

You may have experienced a bug in the API. If it occurs again please report it on the issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug

Another way to guarantee that your application will show a place is to perform a 'Place Report Request' using the Google Places API with your API Key. This will instantly add a place and make it available to your API Key, then if the place is approved by Google if will be available to anyone.

Cheers

Chris